# DRYing my has_many's in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, dry

I have a model class that has, among other things:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions

  has_many :admins, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user, :conditions => "subscriptions.role = #{ROLES[:admin]}"
  has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user, :conditions => "subscriptions.role >= #{ROLES[:subscriber]}"
  has_many :authors, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user, :conditions => "subscriptions.role >= #{ROLES[:author]}"
  has_many :pending_subscribers, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user, :conditions => "subscriptions.pending = true"
end
```

The number of times `:through => :subscriptions, :source => :user` is repeated bothers me.  I know in routes files, you can do `map.with_options`.  Is there something like that for my model associations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`with_options` is actually an extension on [Object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M000291), so you can use it in your `ActiveRecord::Base` as well

```
with_options :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user do |obj|
  obj.has_many :admins, :conditions => "subscriptions.role = #{ROLES[:admin]}"
  obj.has_many :subscribers, :conditions => "subscriptions.role >= #{ROLES[:subscriber]}"
  obj.has_many :authors, :conditions => "subscriptions.role >= #{ROLES[:author]}"
  obj.has_many :pending_subscribers, :conditions => "subscriptions.pending = true"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method that calls `has_many` with the common conditions. Here's one way of drying it up with a block:

```
{ :admins => "subscriptions.role = #{ROLES[:admin]}",
  :subscribers => "subscriptions.role = #{ROLES[:subscriber]}",
  :authors => "subscriptions.role >= #{ROLES[:author]}",
  :pending_subscriptions => "subscriptions.pending = true" }.each do |property, condition| 
  has_many key, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user, :conditions => condition
end
```